# What may cause character encoding not work for CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, character-encoding

I am trying to use Coordino open source PHP project built on CakePhp. On the webpage coding seems to work but when I click to "Soru Sor"(Ask Question) and fill in the title and body parts some special characters like "ı", "ş" not work while "ç" works fine. I have checked the encodings and it is utf-8. 
http://hataaldim.com/questions/531cbbcf2bc5b/satlar-aras-gei
this is the example. What might cause that or where should I look for correction? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly does "I have checked the encodings" mean? Which places did you check the encoding? I'm guessing you missed at least one.

Comment: I checked the default.ctp under app/views/layouts and ask.ctp under app/views/posts but the second one doesnt have any encoding. Definitely I am missing something here but I dont know where. https://github.com/Datawalke/Coordino this is the code of the project

Comment: I installed the project to demo.hataaldim.com and tested with default code which same problem occurred. Now at least I know that I didnt mess anything during translations and changes. Any idea what may cause that problem?